# Three.js - Change JSON Material at runtime

Tags: javascript, json, three.js

Okay so I have imported a multi material object with JSON loader and I'm trying to get access to each material at runtime.
Basicially I like to modify the colors of the imported materials.

Can anyone guide me how to accomplish it, or is it possible at all ?

Thanks.

**JSON**

```
{
    "vertices": [-0.889175,-0.389516,-0.407662,-0.889175,0.521047,-0.407662,-0.889175,-0.389516,-1.31822,-0.889175,0.521046,-1.31822,0.021387,-0.389516,-0.407662,0.021387,0.521047,-0.407662,0.021387,-0.389516,-1.31822,0.021387,0.521046,-1.31822],
    "normals": [-0.577349,-0.577349,-0.577349,-0.577349,-0.577349,0.577349,-0.577349,0.577349,0.577349,-0.577349,0.577349,-0.577349,0.577349,0.577349,-0.577349,0.577349,-0.577349,-0.577349,0.577349,0.577349,0.577349,0.577349,-0.577349,0.577349],
    "faces": [35,2,0,1,3,0,0,1,2,3,35,3,7,6,2,1,3,4,5,0,35,7,5,4,6,0,4,6,7,5,35,0,4,5,1,1,1,7,6,2,35,0,2,6,4,1,1,0,5,7,35,5,7,3,1,1,6,4,3,2],
    "name": "CubeGeometry.2",
    "uvs": [],
    "colors": [],
    "metadata": {
        "version": 3,
        "normals": 8,
        "faces": 6,
        "uvs": 0,
        "colors": 0,
        "materials": 2,
        "vertices": 8,
        "generator": "io_three",
        "type": "Geometry"
    },
    "materials": [{
        "specularCoef": 50,
        "DbgIndex": 1,
        "wireframe": false,
        "opacity": 1,
        "visible": true,
        "DbgName": "material2",
        "depthTest": true,
        "blending": "NormalBlending",
        "transparent": false,
        "shading": "phong",
        "colorEmissive": [0,0,0],
        "colorDiffuse": [0.64,0.64,0.64],
        "DbgColor": 15597568,
        "depthWrite": true,
        "colorSpecular": [0.5,0.5,0.5],
        "vertexColors": false,
        "colorAmbient": [0.64,0.64,0.64]
    },{
        "specularCoef": 50,
        "DbgIndex": 0,
        "wireframe": false,
        "opacity": 1,
        "visible": true,
        "DbgName": "material1",
        "depthTest": true,
        "blending": "NormalBlending",
        "transparent": false,
        "shading": "phong",
        "colorEmissive": [0,0,0],
        "colorDiffuse": [0.64,0.64,0.64],
        "DbgColor": 15658734,
        "depthWrite": true,
        "colorSpecular": [0.5,0.5,0.5],
        "vertexColors": false,
        "colorAmbient": [0.64,0.64,0.64]
    }]
}
```

**JSON loader and add to scene**

```
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();

loader.load( "test.js", function(geometry, materials){
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( materials ) );
scene.add(mesh);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `MultiMaterial` -- formerly `MeshFaceMaterial` -- you can access and change the material colors like so:

```
mesh.material.materials[ 0 ].color.set( 0xff0000 );
mesh.material.materials[ 1 ].color.setRGB( 1, 0, 0 );
```

Study the docs for `THREE.Color()` to see other acceptable formats.

three.js r.73